# Human vs Person

Tags: word-choice

Imagine a database to keep clients' data. Clients can be either humans/persons or companies. For human/person clients there is additional data to be stored, like gender, age. What word works better in this context? My first thought was Person, but as it turned out companies can also be persons (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_personhood). And human client just sounds odd to me. What should I use and why?

Comment: I would describe companies as 'institutions' (the legal niceties notwithsatnding).

Comment: @Dan This raises another question I think. Clients implies business, company is a business organization, and institution is a more wide term, just any organization.

Comment: Personally, I would use "individual" and "organization".  If you were to have a government or an NGO as a client they would not strictly speaking be a business.

Comment: Legal fictions aside, a lot of people regard their pets as people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many philosophers subscribe to the following usages:

***Human*** refers to a member of the biological species *homo sapiens*.

***Person*** is used more generally to refer to things with consciousness and agency; things with selves. In addition to humans, androids, angels, gods, and aliens can all be persons.

Data that is specific to humans like age, gender, etc. might be called ***biographical data***. While it is true that some people use the phrase "company bio" and "company biography," the word "biography" very heavily connotes information about human persons.

If you're just looking for a dichotomy, you might consider using ***individual client*** (for individual humans) versus ***corporate client*** (for companies).

Comment: +1 for Individual vs Corporate (or company).